# Sorting txt lines numerically

Tags: python, python-3.x

I took txt file as input and i want to sort them numerically. How can i do?
The input file as txt:

```
65 1 Hello
78 3 up
78 2 what's
65 2 world
```

i want the output as:

```
message 1:
    65 1 Hello
    65 2 world
message 2:
    78 2 what's
    78 3 up
```

First i need to sort first numbers, then i need to sort second numbers. I thought i can put every line in a list and then sort them. Then i need to write "message n:" before every text group. Finally i need to put them in a new txt file.

Comment: What have you tried? What code have you written and what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I tried to put every line to list and sort with `key=int` but it didn't work.

Comment: Add that code to the question too

Comment: This site is not for receiving free-code. You are expected to do some research and ask about ***your own code***. Show a [mre] of your code and explain what is wrong: Are you getting an error, wrong output? Post example inputs/outputs. You can read more about [ask] and  [How to ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: I know how to ask questions but I am new at this so i couldn't try a lot of possiblities then i didn't find necessary to put my wrong codes. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort them after splitting into separate lines by 1st and second order numbers as:

```
sorted([line.split() for line in file_contents.split('\n')], key = lambda x:(int(x[0]), int(x[1])))
```

results in:

```
[['65', '1', 'Hello'],
 ['65', '2', 'world'],
 ['78', '2', "what's"],
 ['78', '3', 'up']]
```

Then you can play around with this list to have output to your liking! Hint: Go grab the unique 0th index values and change the message number when 0th index is changed. While it is unchanged concat all 2nd index values.

Answer (score 1):

you can use List.sorted:

```
# Using readlines() 
file1 = open('./mytext.txt', 'r') 
Lines = file1.readlines() 
  

Lines.sort(key=lambda line: (int(line.split(" ")[0]),int(line.split(" ")[1])),reverse=False)


print(Lines)



temp=0
count=0
for i in Lines:
    value = int(i.split(" ")[0])
    if(value!=temp):
        count+=1
        print("message {0}:".format(count))
        print("    "+(i).replace("\n",""))
        temp=value
    else:
        print("    "+(i).replace("\n",""))
        temp=value
```

**Output**

[image]

IF you have to sort first in descending order using first-row value and then in ascending using the second-row value

This can be done by assigning negative to the second number

```
# Using readlines() 
file1 = open('./mytext.txt', 'r') 
Lines = file1.readlines()   

Lines.sort(key=lambda line: (int(line.split(" ")[0]),-int(line.split(" ")[1])),reverse=True)
    
print(Lines)    

temp=0
count=0
for i in Lines:
    value = int(i.split(" ")[0])
    if(value!=temp):
        count+=1
        print("message {0}:".format(count))
        print("    "+(i).replace("\n",""))
        temp=value
    else:
        print("    "+(i).replace("\n",""))
        temp=value
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: It should be like i gave it in example. We need to group first numbers and then sort the seconds.

Comment: @Alexandra added answer , also included how to sort first using descending first column value and ascending second row value

Comment: The second part is not relevant. Both numbers need to be ascending... By the way `reverse=False` is the default so it is not needed

Comment: @Tomerikoo my first answer was same i was using a different data set :) then thought to add both just so that it will be use full if any one want to do secondary sort with different order